# Dropzone.js - maxFilesize increase not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm using [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for my website. I'm in the need of uploading bigger files than the default `maxFilesize` of **500MB**.

I tried to change the number in the *.js file*. Now the file seems to be accepted but there is no (visible?) progress in the upload. The file has no red cross and is stuck at zero percent of the upload.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Or is this some kind of bug?

Comment: is it possible your server doesn't allow that big of a file to be uploaded? or the post size is limited below that amount?

Comment: @Sybio: There is no code. I'm using this plugin - as stated :)

Comment: @ChenAsraf: When I use the Django Admin it works just fine. The problem seems to be with `Dropzone.js`

Comment: Why are you changing maxFilesize in .js file instead of plugin option while calling?

Comment: it doesn't matter, does it? my problem is that it's not working

Comment: Hi, do you have any error in your console? Could you provide an URL where I could try your upload?

Comment: no error at all... and no, sorry, the project is way too much under construction now :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just tested it in Chrome and it worked fine. (Which browser are you using?)

It might be that your upload is just taking so long that you don't see an update immediately.

First things first: you shouldn't change properties in the `.js` file itself. This way you wont be able to upgrade to a newer version of Dropzone without headaches. So configure your dropzone the way it's recommended on the website.

About the upload,... it's really hard to tell what might be wrong without a look at it. What I suggest, is that you add some kind of debugging information on the status updates, to see if it's really just your upload being very slow.

Try this code and see if it doesn't solve your problem:

```html
<form id="my-dropzone" action="/target" class="dropzone"></form>

<script>
  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFilesize: 500,
    init: function() {
      this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
        console.log("File progress", progress);
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

If you can see the console output in regular intervals then the upload is working fine but just takes a while to finish.

Comment: Note: your php.ini contains a upload_max_filesize value to keep sufficiently high or it will fail silently. /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 4):

The Dropzone.options must be out of document.ready or it wont work.

Comment: What does that mean? I always have dropzones in document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, because this post is from along time ago.

I solved it changing in the php.ini file parameter 'post_max_size' from my server. Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.

And then reboot the Apache Server.

Answer (score -2):

Add to httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory "/tmp/">
    LimitRequestBody 256000
</Directory>
```

After, **restart apache**!

Reference: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-limiting-upload-size/