# Why Dropzone.js not able to upload file bigger than 250MB

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am trying to upload a file bigger than 250Mb but dropzone.js is not able to upload it. I have checked the server configuration and its looks fine. Here are the more details

```
upload_max_filesize=1024M
post_max_size=1024M
```

Its successfully uploading the file less than 250MB. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this could help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143884/dropzone-js-maxfilesize-increase-not-working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143884/dropzone-js-maxfilesize-increase-not-working)

Comment: I saw your answer and found that i have same issue. Its working fine on chrome. Only Mozila has the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Put these in your code where you are sending your file to upload

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '1000M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000M');
```

This works for me