# Bug on Dropzone maxFilesize

Tags: jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone in uploading image, but I have a problem in maxFilesize of it, I put `maxFilesize: 50` and according to it's document it is 50mb, but when I upload image that is more than 1mb it says that it's too large.

On my research I found a [codepen](https://codepen.io/gogl92/pen/YraxJR), when I also try to make the `maxFilesize: 50`, upload a 2mb image and when I hover the image it also said that the image is too large.

Here is the sample of my code

```
$('#imageUploader').dropzone({
    paramName: 'file',
    maxFilesize: 50,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    uploadMultiple: false,
    success: function( file, response ) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function( file, errorMessage ) {
     console.log(errorMessage);
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log('Complete');
    }
  });
```

I don't know if it's really a bug or I just missing something to my code

I have tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143884/dropzone-js-maxfilesize-increase-not-working)
I added this one in my code

```
 init: function() {
  this.on("uploadprogress", function(file, progress) {
    console.log("File progress", progress);
  });
}
```

but still has an error

when I try to pass 1mb below the file `path, filename,basename,pathname,realPath` has a value but when I pass 4mb image it doesn't have a value

I'm using laravel for backend

Comment: Which browser are you using? Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17143884/5071902

Comment: I'm also using chrome

Answer (score 0):

```js
addedfile: function (file) {
            if (file.size > (1024 * 1024 * 5)) // not more than 5mb
            {
                this.removeFile(file);
                alert("Only 5 mb file size is allowed");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a few things to increase the size limits here, if you're using NGINX you'll need to add a directive similar to this in your config file:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

and in your `php.ini` (if apache this is all you need to do)

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```