# How to upload a large file in laravel voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, filesize, voyager

I am using laravel with voyager as the admin panel. I am trying to upload a video through voyager media picker with file size 3GB but every time I do so I get the following message:

`File is too big (3015.93MiB). Max filesize: 256MiB.`

I changed the `upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` both to `4G` But I still get the same issue.

I tried adding the following lines to .htaccess

`php_value upload_max_filesize 4G`

`php_value post_max_size 4G`

Still same issue

I tried amending the php.ini file found in vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4/php.ini and vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0/php.ini to the following:

```
[PHP]
upload_max_filesize = 4G

post_max_size = 4G
variables_order = EGPCS
```

Still I get the same issue.

I have also created a new file in the public_html directory called .user.ini and here is the content of the file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 4G

post_max_size = 4G
```

I still get the same issue.

I am really stuck and have no idea what to do, does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try changing the values to `M` instead of `G` ,`4000M` instead of `4G` and restart your server

Comment: Same issue. I furthered my research on how to increase the limit, I found out that there is a dropzone-js file which has a default 256MiB file size upload. But the problem is that I have no idea where to find this file. I searched over all my files but unfortunately I found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that you need to do:

#### PHP changes

First, you will need to increase the size of the file upload in the PHP configuration file. You can do this by editing the `php.ini` file and changing the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` values.

If you don't know where your `php.ini` file is located, you can create a new file called `info.php` and add the following code:

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then, you can access the `info.php` file in your browser and it will show you the location of your `php.ini` file.

After you have increased the size of the file upload in the PHP configuration file, you will need to restart your web server. And then visit the `info.php` file again to make sure that the changes have been applied.

#### Dropzone.js changes

The Laravel Voyager Media Manager uses the [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzone.dev/) library to handle the file upload. So, you will need to increase the size of the file upload in the Dropzone definition.

The default size of the file upload in the Laravel Voyager Media Manager is 256MB.

For this, we will copy the media manager view file from the Laravel Voyager package to our project. You can do this by running the following command:

- Create the `resources/views/vendor/voyager/media` directory if it doesn't exist:

```bash
mkdir -p resources/views/vendor/voyager/media
```

- Copy the `manager.blade.php` file from the Laravel Voyager package to our project:

```bash
cp vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/media/manager.blade.php resources/views/vendor/voyager/media/manager.blade.php
```

Now, you can open the `resources/views/vendor/voyager/media/manager.blade.php` file and set the `maxFilesize` value to the desired size.

- Open the file and go to line `847`:

```bash
nano +847 resources/views/vendor/voyager/media/manager.blade.php
```

And inside the `dropzone` function add a new line and set the `maxFilesize` value to the desired size:

```js
...
            dropzone.dropzone({
                // Add the line below
                maxFilesize: 500,
                timeout: 180000,
                url: '{{ route('voyager.media.upload') }}',
...
```

Save the file and you are done. After that go to the media manager page and do a hard refresh to make sure that the cache is cleared and try to upload a file that is larger than the default size.

[Source](https://devdojo.com/bobbyiliev/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-file-upload-in-laravel-voyager-media-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Since this has not been answered yet, i will share some knowledge for future reference for others.

There are a few factors need to consider.

1. Check your server configs if it allows 4000M of upload (you can test normal file uploading) before proceeding to test the `dropzone.js`

As some servers (eg: nginx or others) has default values as well, hence they could also be limiting you from  uploading large file sizes.

2. Change the uploading limit values php.ini (which seems that you've done it).
3. Check the `dropzone.js` settings in assets folder, as `dropzone` it has its own configurations.

Do check a possible answer here: [Dropzone.js - maxFilesize increase not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17281332/4701387)

4. Make sure to increase timeout to few mins on all of the above.

Default timeout is 30sec, which is not enough time if you dont have super fast internet, so need to increase timeout settings for your `server`, `php` and also `dropzone.js`.

Lastly, if all fails, you need to `Inspect Element` your network when you upload, it should give you an idea what the error is to overcome it.